# Why does PostgreSQL apparently coerce a string with timestamp to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` even without the time zone offset?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

I am on PostgreSQL v11.10, and have the `TimeZone` set to `UTC`.

When I say `select '2021-02-16 17:45+00' at time zone 'America/New_York';`, I get `2021-02-16 12:45:00`, which is correct and expected.

However, when I say `select '2021-02-16 17:45' at time zone 'America/New_York';`, I get the same result.

It seems like both strings are coerced to `timestamp with time zone`, which seems a bit counterintuitive to me in the case of the latter one.  Why does PostgreSQL behave like that?  Is it documented in the manual (I looked at the following places: [AT TIME ZONE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT), then [Date/Time Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-datetime.html) and also [Date/Time Input Interpretation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datetime-input-rules.html) and [Handling of Invalid or Ambiguous Timestamps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datetime-invalid-input.html), all to no avail).

Comment: Because you have `TimeZone = UTC` then `'2021-02-16 17:45+00'` and `'2021-02-16 17:45'` are the same thing as Postgres uses the `TimeZone` setting as the tz when one is not provided.

Comment: See here [Timestamps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) 8.5.1.3. Time Stamps: 'PostgreSQL never examines the content of a literal string before determining its type, and therefore will treat both of the above as timestamp without time zone'. So `'2021-02-16 17:45+00'` becomes `'2021-02-16 17:45'`.

Answer (score 2):

Because your `TimeZone` is set to `UTC`, any timestamp without a specified timezone will be interpreted as local to the UTC timezone.  Since you as asking for a timestamp to be interpreted as `America/New_York`, Postgres will first interpret the timestamp as a UTC timestamp, then do the math to convert it to `America/New_York`.

Note that if you actually look at the types being sent to Postgres, it is not coercing into `timestamp with timezone` unless you specify it:

```
edb=# select pg_typeof('2021-02-16 17:45' at time zone 'America/New_York');
          pg_typeof          
-----------------------------
 timestamp without time zone
(1 row)

edb=# select pg_typeof('2021-02-16 17:45+00' at time zone 'America/New_York');
          pg_typeof          
-----------------------------
 timestamp without time zone
(1 row)

edb=# select pg_typeof('2021-02-16 17:45+00'::timestamptz at time zone 'America/New_York');
          pg_typeof          
-----------------------------
 timestamp without time zone
(1 row)

edb=# select pg_typeof('2021-02-16 17:45+00'::timestamptz);
        pg_typeof         
--------------------------
 timestamp with time zone
(1 row)

edb=# select pg_typeof('2021-02-16 17:45+00'::timestamp);
          pg_typeof          
-----------------------------
 timestamp without time zone
(1 row)
```